# Parsing a date from C# to javascript with D3js

Tags: c#, javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to parse a c# DateTime object, returned as Json from my controller, to an appropriate javascript date format for input to D3js.

In my controller, I return some random values for now:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DataBlob()
{
    var list = new List<object>();
    var rnd = new Random();
    var start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
    var range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new TrendData
        {
            Depth = rnd.Next(i, 100),
            Id = i,
            Speed = rnd.Next(i, 100),
            Time = start.AddDays(rnd.Next(range)),
            Weight = rnd.Next(i, 100)
        });
    }

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in my view, I have d3 component that fetches the data with d3.json(..):

```
...
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
...

d3.json('@Url.Action("DataBlob", "Trend")', function (error, data) {
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== "Time"; }));

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        console.log("Before: " + new Date(parseInt(d.Time.substr(6))));
        tmp = new Date(parseInt(d.Time.substr(6)));
        d.Time = parseDate(tmp);
        console.log("After: " + d.Time);
    });
}
```

Here's a snapshot of the array I'm given from my json call:
[image]

When inspecting the console, I see the following from my console.log statement:

`Before: Thu Mar 13 2014 10:53:17 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)`

followed by this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'substring'`

I was hoping someone could help me parse these dates correctly, as I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The result of `tmp = new Date(parseInt(d.Time.substr(6)));` is a Date object, it doesn't require further parsing. You may want formatting though, so `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d")` [according do the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting), so you may want to rename that variable.

Comment: Ah, thanks. How could I miss that? :$
Feel free to add it as an answer for me to accept!

Comment: Heaven forbid!! Score points for RTFM? ;-)

Comment: Haha :) Good point. Guess I've misinterpreted it anyway :) Have to read it more closely next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983207/parsing-a-date-from-c-sharp-to-javascript-with-d3js#comment35097937_22983207) already answered it,

The result of

```
tmp = new Date(parseInt(d.Time.substr(6)));
```

is a `Date` object, it doesn't require further parsing.  You may want formatting though, so

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d")
```

according do the [**documentation**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting), so you may want to rename that variable.